# How to create a custom styled util for styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to create a new util named higherStyled and this function to just pass &&& { } to the child style.

You can use &&& instead of using the !important attribute to styles. https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity

```
const higherStyled = (component, style) => styled(component)` 
&&& {
${style}
}
`
```

So, I need to use this util for my some components, but when I create a custom function I can't use some features of styled like `${({theme}) => theme.colors.myColor}` because it cant find theme.

I don't want to manually add `&&&` to the fields. I need to create a util to make management more comfortable. What should I do?

Comment: Did you wrap your component with `ThemeProvider`?